# Sending data via bluetooth with a button in Swift

Tags: swift, button, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to send data via bluetooth with a button click. I'm able to send the data when opening the app with the code below:

```
var manager: CBCentralManager!
var device: CBPeripheral?
var characteristics: [CBCharacteristic]?
var serviceUUID = "1234"
var char1 = "FFE1"
let deviceName = "HMSoft"

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    DidDiscoverChar.text = "Characteristic found!"

    device = peripheral
    characteristics = service.characteristics

    var value: UInt8 = 1

    let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

    for characteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!
    {
        if(characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FFE1")
        {
            device?.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristic,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)

        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to send it with a button:

```
@IBAction func ledOn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var value: UInt8 = 1
    let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

    device?.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristics,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
}
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[CBCharacteristic]?' to expected argument type 'CBCharacteristic'

It seems like an easy task, but as a newbie I'm stuck.

EDIT: (Response to rmaddy´s answer)

as you suggested, it did work iterating through the array, shown below.

```
@IBAction func ledOn(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var value: UInt8 = 1

    let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)


    for characteristic in characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!
    {

        if(characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FFE1")
        {
            device?.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristic,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)

        }
    }
}
```

As I want to improve as a programmer, I want the code to be more efficient. So I thought I could do the iteration outside the button function to avoid the iteration every time I push the button. to illustrate I did a simple example in playground:

```
var characteristicFFE1: String = ""
var array = ["r1", "r2", "r3", "FFE1", "r4"]

for uuidString in array {
    if uuidString == "FFE1" {
       characteristicFFE1 = uuidString
    }
}
```

And then use characteristicFFE1 directly in writeValue in IBAction like this:

```
@IBAction func ledOn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
var value: UInt8 = 1
let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

device?.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristicsFFE1,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
}
```

I tried to accomplish the above, as shown below:

```
var characteristicFFE1: CBCharacteristic?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for characteristic in characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!  //ERROR HERE
    {

        if(characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "FFE1")
        {
            characteristicFFE1 = characteristic

        }
    }
```

but I get the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

anyone know how to get around this? Ive read about optionals and unwrapping, but still confused here.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: the last line in IBAction function, "characteristics" is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
  device?.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristics,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
```

You want to send an optional array of type `CBCharacteristic` which you declared here

```
   var characteristics: [CBCharacteristic]?
```

while the parameter should be value of type `CBCharacteristic` that you should initialize before using like this

```
   var characteristics: CBCharacteristic?
```

Here is method signature from [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue)

> func writeValue(_ data: Data, 
>               for characteristic: CBCharacteristic,type:CBCharacteristicWriteType)

Comment: thanks for reply! where should I initialize it? I tried doing it in the IBAction function, but then I got an warning to use "let" instead of "var". After changing it to "let" I got a new error on the same line as the first time: Constant 'characteristic' used before being initialized.   Any ideas?